# AWS Secrets Manager without setsecret or testsecret

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to create a secret in secrets manager to be rotated periodically every 30 days but without specifying the end service. Is it possible to remove the setSecret and testSecret sections from my lambda? or will it gives me errors?

Comment: Did you try this? What happened? It would seem reasonable that if you don't actually have a database or service to apply/test the new secret with then you can probably stub out these methods to report success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an empty implementation has worked for me:

```
def set_secret(service_client, arn, token):
    """Set the secret

    This method should set the AWSPENDING secret in the service that the secret belongs to. For example, if the secret is a database
    credential, this method should take the value of the AWSPENDING secret and set the user's password to this value in the database.

    Args:
        service_client (client): The secrets manager service client

        arn (string): The secret ARN or other identifier

        token (string): The ClientRequestToken associated with the secret version

    """
    # This is where the secret should be set in the service
    pass
```